# Assigning strings with ')' character to a variable in postscript

Tags: postscript

I want to assign "asd)asd" this string to a variable. But whenever I do that it does not work.

I have a similar code with strings like "asdasd" and that worked. But whenever I introduce ')' character it stops working

```
%this works
%!PS-Adobe-1.0
/units (asdasd) def
/Times-Roman findfont 20 scalefont setfont
300 300 moveto units show
showpage

%this does not 
%!PS-Adobe-1.0
/units (asd)asd) def
/Times-Roman findfont 20 scalefont setfont
300 300 moveto units show
showpage
```

Comment: It seems you did not investigate a lot finding the obvious solution. Maybe even *accept* one of the answers given.

Answer (score 3):

The character `)` is a special token in PostScript, if you want to use it in a string there are several ways. Firstly you can use a hex string:

```
/units <61736429617364> def
```

Alternatively, in common with other languages, you can 'escape' special tokens in strings. You can find this described on page 29 of the Third edition PostScript Language Reference Manual.

```
/units (asd\)asd) def
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If it is the case that I am not allowed to modify the string itself (I have to keep it as it is) then is there any other way around?

Comment: Well no. Why do you care about keeping the string 'as it is' ? You're putting it in a PostScript program..... The result of escaping the parentheses is that the string **will** be the same. I can't believe your original string came delimited with parentheses, so you are already clearly modifying the string, in that sense. Oh and of course writing it as a Hex string does leave it unchanged. Failing all those there are other ways (eg you could store the characters in an array then add them one by one to an empty string., This **is** a programming language....

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to put `asd)asd` as-is in your program, as long as it's just one line (ie, it doesn't have a new line character in it), and you do it outside any `{ }` (ie, you can't use this in a proc):

```
currentfile 1000 string readline asd)asd
pop
```

Your string goes from *exactly one space* after **readline**, till the end of the line.

To define the name `/units`:

```
/units currentfile 1000 string readline asd)asd
pop def
```

Of course, adjust the string size (1000 in the example) according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "psrefman.pdf" (*PostScript Language Reference Manual ®, SECOND EDITION*) and read section "**Strings**" in "**Chapter 3: Language**" (page 28). It's all there:

> Within a text string, the \ (backslash) character is treated as an “escape”
>   for various purposes, such as including unbalanced parentheses, non-printing characters, and the \ character itself. The character immediately following the \ determines its precise interpretation.

If you prefer `ps3refman.pdf` (*PostScript ® LANGUAGE REFERENCE, third edition*) instead, it's on page 29, Chapter "**Language**", section "**Syntax**", subsection "**ASCII Encoding**", sub-subsection "**Strings**", paragraph "**Literal Text Strings**".